# Nodejs, Winston: Log entry getting duplicated

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I am using winston to save the logs and I am saving the logs to a file.

```
var winston = require('winston');
var moment = require('moment');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        name: 'info-file',
        filename: 'console.log',
        timestamp : function() {return moment().utcOffset(330).format('DD-MM HH:mm'); },
        level: 'info'
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        name: 'debug-file',
        filename: 'console.log',
        timestamp : function() {return moment().utcOffset(330).format('DD-MM HH:mm'); },
        level: 'debug'
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        name: 'error-file',
        filename: 'console.log',
        timestamp : function() {return moment().utcOffset(330).format('DD-MM HH:mm'); },
        level: 'error'
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        name: 'unhandled-error-file',
        filename: 'console.log',
        timestamp : function() {return moment().utcOffset(330).format('DD-MM HH:mm'); },
        handleExceptions: true
    })
 ]
});
```

This is the command I am running:

```
router.get('/exercise_excel_entry', function(req,res){
  logger.log('info', "info testing");
  logger.log('debug', "debug testing");
  logger.log('error', "error testing");
  res.render('exercise_excel_entry');
});
```

This is the output saved in the file:

```
{"level":"info","message":"info testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"error","message":"error testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"info","message":"info testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"info","message":"info testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"error","message":"error testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"debug","message":"debug testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"error","message":"error testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
{"level":"error","message":"error testing","timestamp":"04-02 11:51"}
```

I don't understand why the info and the error tagged logs are getting duplicated

Answer (score 0):

As per winston docs:

> winston allows you to define a level property on each transport which
>   specifies the maximum level of messages that a transport should log.

The keyword here is *maximum*.

default logging levels are:

```
{ error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, verbose: 3, debug: 4, silly: 5 }
```

So in your case:

- `info-file` will log messages with level 'info' or above (error &
  warn).
- `debug-file` will log messages with level 'debug' or above
  (error, warn, info & verbose).
- `error-file` will log messages with
  level 'error' or above (everything except unhandled exceptions).
- `unhandled-error-file` will log messages with level 'unhandled-error'
  only.

and you have used the filename `console.log` for all the transports.

So the sequence of logs is as follows:

```
logger.log('info', "info testing");    // both info-file & debug-file transport logs it
logger.log('debug', "debug testing");  // only debug-file transport logs it
logger.log('error', "error testing");  // info-file, debug-file and error-file transports logs it
```

So that explains the multiple entries for `info` & `error` messages in the log file.

**EDIT**

Not the best solution (*as this will add blank lines for levels not to log*):

```
new (winston.transports.File)({
    name: 'info-file',
    filename: 'console.log',
    timestamp : function() {return moment().utcOffset(330).format('DD-MM HH:mm'); },
    level: 'info',
    filters: [function (level, msg, meta) {
        return (level === 'info') ? msg : '';
    }],
    formatter: function(options) {
        return msg === '' ? '' : { level: options.level, timestamp: options.timestamp, message: options.message, meta: options.meta };
    }
})
```

Comment: oh...so how can I make the message send message for that priority level only?

Comment: Currently I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: this thing will just bloat my logs unnecessarily...so there is no way to get a single log entry under these categories?

Comment: You can use [filters & rewriters](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#filters-and-rewriters) and [custom log format](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#custom-log-format) for each transport to pass only if the message level matches the transporter level otherwise just return a blank message.

Comment: I have edited my response to give you a sample code of how to do it for one transport. You can repeat it for the others. But I must say that it might slow down your logger.

Comment: If you are mainly concerned about the log file size then you can use [winston-daily-rotate-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file).

Comment: Just writing the same line 3 times is just a waste with redundant information. Eventually the large log file also will take time to open. May implement a system like you suggested about logging in different file every day

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore a specific type of message if you define your own custom "format"

```
const {
  createLogger,
  format,
  transports
} = require('winston');

// Ignore log messages if they have specific log type
const ignoreInfo = format((info, opts) => {
  if (info.level === 'info') {
    return false;
  }
  return info;
});

const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(
    ignoreInfo(),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
});

// Outputs: {"level":"error","message":"Public error to share"}
logger.log({
  level: 'error',
  message: 'Public error to share'
});

// Messages with level info will not be written when logged.
logger.log({
  level: 'info',
  message: 'This is super secret - hide it.'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but removing the `silly` log fixed my issue

```
_logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        // removed:
        // new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'silly'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'debug'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'verbose'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'http'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'info'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'warn'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: logsPathAndFilename, level: 'error'}),
    ],
});
```